# How to use shortcode to get the second to newest post?

Tags: posts, functions, shortcode

I've done considerable research, and tried multiple solutions to my task, and currently have found a way but i know it is not the best, so hoping for input to do this better.

**The task**

I am using [Shortcode in Menus plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-in-menus/) combined with custom shortcodes to display between one and three of the latest blog posts in my site's main menu.

[image: The three recent posts in the menu].

For each menu link, it's a menu item added using that plugin, with the title and link each set via a different shortcode: [image: menu item added using that plugin, with the title and link each set via a different shortcode]

The way it will work, is I have three menu items added in WordPress menu editor, each using a shortcode to pull one post - one pulls the most recent, one pulls the next most recent, and so on. I currently have 2 shortcodes - one pulling title, one pulling permalink. (This question is not technically about it, but I think i could do it with one shortcode, and `$atts` to grab title or link, so feel free to chime on that too).

**The issue with my code**

This pulls the latestlink ok, but to pull the second most recent, i tried using `offest` - which is commented out below, as it was pulling the most recent - but setting `offset` to `2`, or `3`, does not do anything. What does work, is setting `'posts_per_page' => 3, 'offest' => 3,`.

```
add_shortcode('latest_blog_post_link', 'get_latest_blog_post_link');

function get_latest_blog_post_link($atts, $content = null) {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        // 'offest' => 1,
        'cat' => '38, 21, 30, 39, 10, 8, 26, 20, 22, 18, 9, 24, 11' // replace this number with your category's ID
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        $latest_post = get_permalink($post);
    }
    return $latest_post;
}
```

So my question is, is there a better way to do this? Do I have to set `posts_per_page` to a value higher than `1` for offset to work?

Comment: **You misspelled `offset`** - you used *offest*.. So try with `'offset' => 1` ?

Comment: You are right, and I am embarrassed but happy you found it @SallyCJ! It works as it should now. Is the best practice to answer my own question now?

Comment: I just wasn't 100% sure that you indeed had that typo in your actual code, hence I didn't write an answer. So yes, maybe you should write it on your own :)

Comment: @BenBlue @SallyCJ one of you should write an answer mentioning the `offset` typo

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to set `posts_per_page` to a value higher than `1` for
> offset to work?

No, you do not have to, offset works just fine with `'posts_per_page' => 1`. But then, it did not work for you simply because you **misspelled** 'offset' as 'offest':

- The code that you used was `'offest' => 1`
- but the correct one should be `'offset' => 1`

So just correct the spelling and then it would work as expected.